# Can't get rid of huge left indent in AndroidStudio (screenshot)

Tags: android-studio

[image: android studio with big margin]

Hi, does anyone know what is it on the left?

It is unfoldable, non-draggable, useless and empty area across entire code. It appears in every opened class. If you click on it, you'll set a breakpoint. You can not collapse it. I do not remember how or why I got this, but then I didn't find any key or menu or button combination to heal this bug.

THis is the last Android Studio 3.6.3. And the same was before upgrade.

Please help, it eats my space and nerves!

**UPD**  Gutter icons look ok.

[image: gutter icons]

Comment: Have tried messing with the gutter icons to see if it fixes itself? Right click on the gutter to get to these settings.

Comment: what is gutter exactly, where? I could guess, but if you may point me... And yes, I clicked there all around like in crazy quest PC game.

Answer (score 1):

Just an FYI to anyone that visits this thread - its February of 2024 and this still works:-) This was giving me trouble in one project, but not another so it must be project specific but still couldn't find a way to disable that HUGE waste of space. I even consulted ChatGPT and although it had good recommendations, none of them worked. Wow - who would of thought to put that function under 'Exit for Distraction Free mode'.

Appreciate your diligence in finding the fix and posting the remedy.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your gutter icons are messed up. Check via the settings or the context menu on the gutter (i.e. where the line numbers are).

[image: gutter popup]

Comment: Gutter icons look ok. See screenshot in UPD

Answer (score 0):

After 2 months of terribly inconvenient work I finally found the cause. To turn it off do

**View - Appearance - Exit Distraction Free mode.**

Amazingly, but this big white indent was intended to not distract me (from what? nothing else has changed).